# Make UIViewController conform AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate not working

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, camera

I'm working on creating custom camera that uses photo output to capture photo.

When user taps capture button, `photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)` is called, which takes second parameter as `self` representing `UIViewController`, because `UIViewController` conforms `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`.

But, 1 strange warning comes up when implementing `func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)` with message -

**Instance method 'photoOutput(*:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'photoOutput(*:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)' of protocol 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'**

Also, crash occurs when tap capture button with error message -

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:**

Even if settings have format dictionary which is not nil.

But when I implement a custom class that conforms `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`, there are no warnings and it worked well.

So I'm curious.. Shouldn't `UIViewController` conform `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`? If it's not, why?

Error Example:

```
final class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
   ...
   @IBAction func captureButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard isSessionRunning else { return }

        if let previewLayerOrientation = previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation {
            let photoOutputConnection = photoOutput?.connection(with: .video)
            photoOutputConnection?.videoOrientation = previewLayerOrientation
        }

        guard let photoOutput = self.photoOutput else { return }

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Well-done Example:

```
final class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
   ...
   @IBAction func captureButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard isSessionRunning else { return }

        guard let photoOutput = self.photoOutput else { return }

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        let processor = CameraCaptureProcessor(photoOutput: photoOutput, settings: settings)
        self.capturedDelegate = processor

        processor.capturePhoto()
    }
   ...
}

final class CameraCaptureProcessor: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    private var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    private(set) var settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings!

    convenience init(photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings) {
        self.init()
        self.photoOutput = photoOutput
        self.settings = settings
    }

    func capturePhoto() {
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been nearly a year since this been posted, I just came across it now after I've been experiencing the exact same thing and it puzzled me for a few hours before I came across the explanation.

I was following an old example which can be found [here](https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/).

For me the issues was due to Swift Modules. In the example a custom `Error` is introduced in the following way

```
class CameraController: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    enum Error: Swift.Error {

        case noDeviceAvailable

        case captureSessionMissing

    }
...
```

By conforming to the delegate protocol and implementing the method within the scope of the `CameraController`

```
class CameraController: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    ...

    //MARK: - AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) { ... }

    ...
```

Your are essentially causing the compiler to trigger a warning because the `Error` type in the delegate method doesn't match the `CameraController.Error` type available inside the scope.

The solution is to either move the custom `Error` definition outside the scope of the class or explicitly tell the compiler that the delegate method uses `Swift.Error` as such

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Swift.Error?) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It really helped me!

Comment: you are absolutely a life saver!!!